# how to Phone Number Validation Like USA format in android?

Tags: android, validation

I want to Phone number Validation Like USA. Example 111-111-1111 or 111 111 1111 or (111) 111 1111 Like this. and I am using this Regular Expression but It give me Error:

```
string MatchPhoneNumberPattern = "^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$";
```

> **Error** Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )

How to solve this error and how to Phone number validation Like USA Phone no Format 111-111-1111?
if another solution then tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Check [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) library. It is maintained by google and optimized to Android.

Comment: Please if you have any demo then send me.please

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches());
}
public static boolean isValidPhone(CharSequence target) {
    return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Patterns.PHONE.matcher(target).matches());
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.